# How do you connect to database inside a function

Tags: php, database, function, mysqli

How do you connect to database inside a function? ...I currently do this:

**basic connect to db:**

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'foo');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

**The function:**

When writing a function I have to include the connect query again inside it

```
    function cleanup($str, $real) {
           if(get_magic_quotes_gpc() == true){
                $str = stripslashes($str);
        }

         $str = htmlspecialchars($str);

   if($real == true) {

       // connection query here again

        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'foo');

        $str  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$str);

        }
         return $str;
    }
```

This seems silly to me as I'm having to add host, user and pass details twice, I'd like it that the basic connection would somehow take care of both

Comment: Why don't you pass `$conn` into your function as a parameter? Or use a class, and set conn up as a class attribute?

Comment: You don't connect to the DB on a per-function basis. That's incredibly wasteful. You generally connect **ONCE** in a some kind of a startup-script, then reuse that connection everywhere else in your scrip(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). You don't automatically have access to variables defined in the global scope when inside a function.
You can 'import' variables into the function's local scope like this:

```
function cleanup($str, $real) {
    global $conn;

    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc() == true) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }

    $str = htmlspecialchars($str);

    if($real == true) { 
        $str  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$str);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
global $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'foo');
```

Make the $conn instance of your database global, then any of your code can make use of it.

```
if($real == true) {
    global $conn;
    $str  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$str);
  }
  return $str;
}
```

Comment: I seem to be getting an error 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';''

Comment: Am I suppost to put global in front of main connect query as thats whats giving me the error or just add `global $conn;` to the function?

Comment: That is what causes the error indeed. Global should only be used inside the function.